# Maven: Ignore a specific artifact without failing the build

Tags: java, maven, artifactory

I am trying to build Apache CXF locally. It does not work behind a maven proxy (e.g. JFrog Artifactory), because CXF's transitives dependencies contain a dependency with an invalid `pom.xml` file:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project cxf-rt-transports-jms: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-jms:bundle:3.4.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.activemq:activemq-pool:jar:5.15.9 -> org.apache.activemq:activemq-jms-pool:jar:5.15.9 -> org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.0.1B_spec:jar:1.0.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.0.1B_spec:jar:1.0.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.geronimo.specs:specs:pom:1.1 from/to nexus-central (https://myrepo.local/maven-central/): Failed to transfer file https://myrepo.local/maven-central/org/apache/geronimo/specs/specs/1.1/specs-1.1.pom with status code 409 -> [Help 1]
```

Artifactory will deliver a 409 if it cannot parse the XML file. In this case, the artifact is `apache.geronimo.specs:specs:pom:1.1`. If you take a look at the XML file, you'll find it is invalid indeed: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/geronimo/specs/specs/1.1/specs-1.1.pom

After line 89 (closing `</developers>`), there is an extra `.

I opened an issue at apache to fix their build: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-8101

In the mean time, I'd like to work with CXF to create a patch an contribute.

Things I tried:

- Install the dependency manually => failed because mvn still looks for updates
- No proxy => not an option for me :(
- Add some excludes locally on the `parent/pom.xml` => didn't help, I will never be able to catch them all (transitive dependencies…).
- Forcing the offending artifacts' version to 1.2. Did not help either, because some projects wil still rely on a specific version.

That said, what are my options?

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Comment: You can manually upload the version with a corrected pom to a hosted artifact repository in your Artifactory. Then you create / use a repository group to access Artifactory, making sure that the local repository is included in that group _before_ Maven Central.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

1. Download `org/apache/geronimo/specs/specs/1.1/specs-1.1.pom` into your local `.m2` path and fix the error.[`You need to be sure all dependencies are available in your local repository`]
2. Try to build with maven command: `-o` (offline)
3. If `-o` doesn't help, try with `-nsu,--no-snapshot-updates` (Suppress SNAPSHOT updates)

Hope it helps you.